# Passing latest date to date parameter in tableau server URL

Tags: tableau-api

My requirements are that i need my parameters to have today's/last working date everytime the dashboard is loaded on tableau server. By appending the URL i am able to do this:
http://tableau_server/t/views/Book2/Sheet1?End_Date=2015-01-01
(The link is just a mock example)
Where End_Date is the parameter which is set to 1st jan when this url is fired.
But what i actually need is to set End_Date to todays date instead of 2015-01-01.
Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: The link is broken. And why don't you use TODAY() function instead of a parameter?

Comment: we have passed the parameters in the custom sql where clause so only the data between the parameter range is fetched.If we use a filter all the data will be fetched.

Comment: Okay. I guess the best way to do that is using a simple script (js perhaps) to compose the link. But I still don't understand, if you have a fixed Start_Date, do you really need a End_Date with today value? Your table contains data beyond today (into the future)?

Comment: No like i said this is just a mock example.According to the different dashboards, i will add Start_Date to the URL also....

Comment: Is there no other way than a js? The thing is this link is embedded in our company site to which i have no admin access so i cannot run a script for this

Comment: Okay, so I imagine you want to pass other days rather than today as well. If it is going to be something like today - 7, okay it's the same approach. But if it's an user defined date, you need to think about the user interface. But back to the question, your best shot is to figure out what today is inside your query. Since Tableau uses MS Jet data engine, NOW() might work

Comment: @jai, in my experience your statement that "if we use a filter all the data will be fetched" is not true. Have you confirmed that assumption on your database by checking the query plan? With most databases, the query optimizer can easily combine where clause conditions from the outer query (which come from the filter shelf) with the nested query (specified in custom sql). And in any case, dates excluded by a filter won't be fetched back to the client, regardless of the query structure (excepting table calculation based filters).

Comment: @AlexBlakemore what we found while working with tableau was it is better to limit your sql data by passing a parameter in the query rather than quick filters.with quick filters the query is run on the enitre db as a subquery and after that filters are applied....if i use date parameters in the query i fetch only the data i want thus saving query time

Comment: @Inox i was thinking on the lines of showing data for the last week or so....which would have start_date and end_date set to dates of last week in the URL.NOW() or TODAY() dont seem to work.It looks like my only option would be to write a script which can recognise such a URL and append the last weeks dates to it and then open it in the browser.Let me know if i have any better options(though it looks unlikely now)

Comment: I believe you need to calculate the the date, convert to a string, and compose the url

Comment: @jai even if filters are applied in an outer query wrapping a sub query, only the rows matching the entire nested query are fetched from the server back to the client. I believe you when you say you get different performance if you push the filter into the subquery, but the improvement is not due to reducing the amount of data that is fetched by the client. The whole query is executed on the database server.